# Adjust CSS inserted from script

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

I was given a code snippet from a company we are working with for integration but the script they have given me is injecting their stylesheet. Is there any way to manipulate or better integrate their code into the site?

This is what they gave me:

```
<div id="aiVwbfPVDo2FdPTRGRWzhF9I8RbaTruD_get_appointment_container">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://providers.doctor.com/siteEnhance/getAppointmentWidget?key=aiVwbfPVDo2FdPTRGRWzhF9I8RbaTruD"></script></div>
```

When I inspect the code with a web browser it shows a stylesheet and button are inserted...how can I manipulate that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CSS isn't in your side, you can't manipulate it, the most you can do is override the styles, take in account the [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Thank you, I will just insert the style overrides with the classes they insert.

Comment: You could manipulate it, just change textContent of the style tag